# How to solve this apt-get error?

Tags: 14.04, apt, libraries, arm

I am getting the following error when i try to use apt-get

> root@imx6qsdl-utopic:~# apt update
>   apt: error while loading shared libraries:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libapt-pkg.so.4.12:t

My CPU is armv7 architecture and I have ubuntu 14.04 Filesystem running on it.

Comment: Can u write full instruction/command u gave (with error)

Comment: The one line isn't enough information.  You'll have to edit your message and add at least 10 to 20 lines of the output.  You'll also have to tell us what you are trying to do.  There are thousand of libraries available to be installed.  Out or the many thousands libraries that could be install, that might be one that isn't .  You could use `apt install` to install the needed library.  It might also be a simple matter of using `apt update` to update your library cache.

Comment: There is just one line of error message. I am not getting any other information